# Binary Search Tree Sequence

Tags: binary-search-tree

I have an assignment question on binary search trees. I have completed this problem but want to make sure I'm doing this correctly. Here is the problem:

Suppose that a certain BST has keys that are integers in this array [8, 22, 25, 28, 36, 39, 49, 50, 72, 90], and we search for 36. Which sequence below cannot be the sequence of keys examined?

```
a)  8, 90, 25, 72, 25, 50, 28, 49, 39, 36 <- cannot be examined
b)  25, 28, 72, 36
c)  28, 90, 39, 25, 36
d)  90, 8, 39, 28, 22, 36 <- cannot be examined
e)  90, 72, 50, 49, 39, 36
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding the question correctly, `c)` also can't be correct, since you would go right (greater) upon seeing `28` and then, in a properly constructed BST, you should never encounter `25`, which is smaller than `28`, in the right-hand sub-tree.

The others I agree with.